# Prevent default (ionChange) ion-checkbox

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

What i´m trying to do is to prevent default event on (ionChange).

I want to be able to set the checkbox checked= true or checked= false

If a condition is true or false.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let classroom of teachersClassrooms">
    <ion-label>{{classroom.name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox color="royal" [checked]="classroom.is_set" (ionChange)="updateClassroom(classroom, $event)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

---

```
updateClassroom(item, cbox: Checkbox){
    //cbox.preventDefault();   ------> Not Work

    if(something){
        cbox.checked = true
    }else{
       cbox.checked = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Have your tried using (ngModelChange) or (change)?

Comment: have you try [(ngModel)]="boolValue" to check/uncheck ur checkbox ?

Answer (score 1):

The comments above are a better approach to the ultimate problem. But to answer the question "what i'm trying to do is to prevent default event on ionChange", the following works in an Ionic 4 template:

```
<ion-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (ionChange)="doSomething()"></ion-checkbox>
```

Comment: I just tried now an unfortunately for me on ionic 4 it is not working.

Comment: not working for me either :/